# PHPStorn em Flatpak Fedora 34, não reconhece o diretorio htdocs do Xampp

Tags: linux, xampp, phpstorm

Instalei Fedora 34 recentemete e junto a IDE, PhpStorn através de pacotes flatpak.

A IDE abre normalmente, entretanto ela não consegue acessar o htdocs do Xammp que fica na pasta /opt/lammp/htdocs.
Mas a pasta /opt Não aparece ao tentar abrir no PhpStorn.

[image: Pasta /opt Não aparece ao tentar abrir um projeto]

Minha pasta /htdocs ja liberei o acesso com o comando:

```
sudo chmod ugo=rwx -R /opt/lampp/htdocs/
```

Tentei usar o comando para abrir o diretorio direto pelo terminal com o comando:

```
flatpak run com.jetbrains.PhpStorm .
```

Porem abriu direto na home do meu usuario.

Pelo que estou entendo parece algum tipo falta de permissão do PhpStorn para acessar está pasta.
Mas não sei como resolver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por enquanto a solução que encontrei foi desinstalar o PhpStorm em Flatpak e instalar via snap.

[image: Mostrando aparecendo]

Agora funciona normalmente.

Answer (score -1):

Voltando depois de um tempo de aprendizado:

Esse tipo de evento acontece, pois o flatpak funciona através de um container.

Desta forma para ter acesso a certos recursos do nosso ambiente de desenvolvimento é necessário usar alguns argumentos na linha de comando. Ou instalar dentro deste container o que precisamos.

Isso lembra muito o docker.

No meu caso, tive um resultado melhor com snap, pois ele funciona de forma diferente e integra com o nosso sistema.

Hoje acredito que o flatpak é uma solução mais elegante, porem que poderia ser mais intuitiva para quem está iniciando.